# How do you show $\sum_{d\mid n} \frac{\mu(d)}{d} =\prod_{p\mid n}\left (1-\frac{1}{p}\right)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

how to prove :$$ \sum_{d\mid n} \frac{\mu(d)}{d} =\prod_{p|n} \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)$$

$p$ is prime.

$\mu : \Bbb N\rightarrow \Bbb R$

$\mu(1)=1$

$ \mu(n)=
\begin{cases}
0  &,\;\;\; \text{if $\,n\,$ is divisible by a square prime number} \\{}\\
(-1)^r &,\;\;\; \text{if $\,n=p_1^1\cdots p_r^1\,$}  \\
\end{cases}
 $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a proof of the first one:
$$
n \prod_{p|n} \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right) = \phi(n) = \sum_{d\mid n} \mu(d) \frac{n}{d} = n \sum_{d\mid n} \frac{\mu(d)}{d}
$$
where the second equality comes from using  Moebius inversion on
$$
n = \sum_{d\mid n} \phi(d)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $f(n)$ be one of these sums. Use that $\mu$ is multiplicative to show that $f$ is multiplicative, and hence you only need to show these results for $n$ equal to the power of a prime...

In general, if $h(n)$ is multiplicative - that is $h(nm)=h(n)h(m)$ when $m,n$ is relatively prime - then $g(n)=\sum_{d|n} h(d)$ is also multiplicative.